# Phonegap Plugin execution lifespan

Tags: mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am wondering if someone can answer the following question for me.

When making a call from JS to a Phonegap custom Plugin, after the plugin returns with either `Status.RESULT` or `Status.ERROR`, does the lifespan of the plugin terminates, meaning when you make another call to the same plugin does it create a new instance of the plugin or does it reuse the same existing instance (Singleton-style)?

I will explain the task I am facing with and perhaps it will clarify any confusion my question may have created.

I've created an app using HTML/JS. I have a plugin `ResourceManagerPlugin` responsible for loading files from CDN and caching these on a mobile device. I am calling my plugin `ResourceManagerPlugin` every time I need a new new file (.json, .png, etc), which is why I was wondering if a new instance of `ResourceManagerPlugin` gets created or if I am using the same instance over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

The same instance is used multiple times.